# autocomplete not showing the selected value in textbox

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

---Ajax----

autocomplete was working fine but if i start to type wi(wipro),while typing wi it was showing drop down list but if i select only wi alone inthe text box

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#company_name").keyup(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/capms_v2/ca_autocomplete/getcompanyName",
        data: {
            keyword: $("#company_name").val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.length > 0) {
                $('#DropdownCompany').empty();
                $('#company_name').attr("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                $('#DropdownCompany').dropdown('toggle');

            }
            else if (data.length == 0) {
                $('#company_name').attr("data-toggle", "");
            }
            $.each(data, function (key,value) {
                if (data.length >= 0)
           $('#DropdownCompany').append('<li role="displayCountries" ><a 
    role="menuitem DropdownCompany" id='+ value['company_id']+ ' Address1='+ value['company_address1']+ ' Address2='+ value['company_address2']+' city='+ value['company_city']+' state='+ value['company_state']+' pincode='+ value['company_zip']+'  class="dropdownlivalue">' 
                        + value['company_name'] + '</a></li>');

            });
        }
    });
});
$('ul#txtcountry').on('click', 'li a', function () {
    $('#company_name').val($(this).text());
    $('#company_id').val($(this).text());


    $('#tableCityID').html( $(this).attr("id") );
    $('#tableCityName').html($(this).text());
    $('#Address1').html($(this).attr("Address1"));
    $('#Address2').html($(this).attr("Address2"));
    $('#city').html($(this).attr("city"));
    $('#state').html($(this).attr("state"));
    $('#pincode').html($(this).attr("pincode"));
   });
   });
```

---

### and this is my html page

```
  <input type="text" id="company_name" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Type company name" data-id="" value="" name="company_name">        
   <ul class="dropdown-menu txtcountry" style="margin-left: 15px;margin-right: 0px;margin-top: -17px;" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu"  id="DropdownCompany"  ></ul>


         ---------------------------
```

for example:
If i select skm animals food product only skm alone showing text box and please click the below url for reference

[image]
Please help if anybody knows thanks in advance

Comment: Use select2 . The URL is https://select2.org/

Comment: what is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Read the the following URL `

```
https://select2.org/`
```

Hope it will solve your requirement.